# Starting a blocking GC Alloc and then getting crash with outOfMemory Exception failed to allocate memory

Tags: android

I am  using Picasso but still getting error

> outofMemoryException failed to allocate Memory

```
Picasso.with(context).load(model.getMetaDataImage()) .fit() .centerCrop() .skipMemoryCache() .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565). into(metaDatamainHolder.meta_image);

Picasso.with(context) .load(AppConstant.profileImage + model.getUserId() + AppConstant.imageMedium) .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE) .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE) .fit().config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) .centerCrop().into(metaDatamainHolder.profileImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use getMemoryClass() or getLargeMemoryClass() on ActivityManager to determine how big your heap could get. Then, use that as a guideline for how much you can allocate before you are likely to get an OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score -1):

Remove fit() which is throwing OutOfMemory Exception. So try without fit() and I think you solved your problem.

Also set in manifest file

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

And also enable multidex true.

Comment: Before i was getting this crash quickly but after this solution getting crash after some time. but still getting crash.

Comment: I have already set this properties
 <application
        android:name=".utils.MyApplication"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
and also multidex true  
       multiDexEnabled true